# Overriding a function still calls parent class before child method

Tags: haxe

I am new to Haxe and only plans to deploy for the web.

So I have a class `A` which has a method name `doThis()`. On class `B`, I inherited class `A`. I override `doThis()` on class `B`. When I check on the debugger, class `A` `doThis()` is being called and then class `B` `doThis()` is called as well.

My intuition is, I have overridden the methods explicitly and the only way I can call the parent is via a `super.doThis()` but it seems it does this automatically. I only want the version of `doThis()` to be `B`. Not `A`'s.

Any thought on why it behaves like this? I think I a missing something here.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post reproducible code example

Answer (score 5):

Without any further information, I'd bet good money that you have your debugger breakpoints on the ***definition*** of `doThis`, when you meant to put them in the ***invocation*** of `doThis` (inside the function body).

Other possible (but less likely) reasons:

- A macro function is inserting a `super.doThis()` call
- A modified Haxe compiler or JS generator is emitting a `super.doThis()` call.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the function you are overriding is the constructor function `new`, calling the parent (super) function is optional. Furthermore, you can stipulate when the parent function is called by adjusting when you call `super.doThis()`.

To illustrate, here is code that only runs the child classes function on [try.haxe](https://try.haxe.org/#bAf94). It sounds like you may have already tried a similar approach, so ensure that you aren't missing some code that you may not be aware is calling the super function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing the right thing.
perhaps add some println to the parent function and the child function to make sure what you describe is what actually happens.

In other words, the debugger is not just playing with you.